# .Net Server-Sent Events using HttpHandler not working

Tags: asp.net, html, httphandler, server-sent-events

I have been trying to implement an event driven push to a client browser. I am using ReactiveX to produce the async task from the events but I can't even get my HttpHandlers to output their response.

I have tried with a simple HttpHandler:

```cs
public class Handler2 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;

        while (startdate.AddMinutes(10) > DateTime.Now)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string responseText = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

            response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}",js.Serialize(responseText)));
            response.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        response.Close();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

with the following client side code:

```js
function initialize() {

    if (window.EventSource == undefined) {
        document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML = "Your browser doesn't support Server Side Events.";
        return;
    }

    var source = new EventSource('Handler2.ashx');

    source.onopen = function (event) {
        document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML += 'Connection Opened.<br>';
    };

    source.onerror = function (event) {
        if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML += 'Connection Closed.<br>';
        }
    };

    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML += event.data + '<br>';
    };
}
```

I have more a more complex HttpTaskAsyncHandler ready to hook up, but I can't even get this working >_<
I get the Connection Opened message, Handler2.ashx appears to remain connected (Looking at Chrome dev tools / Network).

I am, on the other hand, getting some data from a SignalR connection?

```
"ws://localhost:50022/ed4b66c7eb394a8789b5f6a631f4ff09/arterySignalR/connect?.."
```

Have I set it up wrong?
As far as I've seen on other examples, this code should be working as-is. Please could anyone help me. I just want a simple SSE control that I can trigger from server side events.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, are you still not getting this right?

Answer (score 0):

I had given this answer before, but let me elaborate:

Looking at the Network tab in Google Chrome developer tools reveals quite a lot from your http://live.meetscoresonline.com/test-sse.aspx

There are no SSE being generated at all - to see this click on the Others button under Network, this is where you would normally be able to track the SSE data stream

I use the following code in my SSE's with a simple HTTPListener and it works well without the delays you mentioned, and always shows up correctly across browsers when using this [polyfill](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yaffle/EventSource/master/eventsource.min.js)

```
        res.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
        res.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        res.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        res.KeepAlive = True
```

Comment: Hi Charles, I found SignalR which suits my needs.  I have a limited number of users as this will be a saas website so it was the best solution all round ^_^.

Comment: OK cool. SignalR is cool and always works, but I think if you are just pushing from server to client, the i think plain SSE is a very good alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, make sure you follow the exact format that the SSE requires:

> data:my_data_contents_here\n\n

The prefix "data:" is important AND so is the 2 newlines at the end.
Otherwise, the clients will never receive the events.

Here's the description of the standard:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Also, don't close the response, keep it open until you want stop sending events.

So, from the original post:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;
    response.KeepAlive = true; // i think this already defaults to true though
    DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;

    while (startdate.AddMinutes(10) > DateTime.Now)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string responseText = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        
        // If it's just plain text, you can actually use: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"data:{responseText}\n\n");
        response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n",js.Serialize(responseText)));
        response.Flush();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    response.Close();
}
```